# как сделать CustomHeaderView в TableView и сделать ее секцией?

Tags: ios, swift, header, tableview

Сделал tableViewCell файл xib. Все задал заработало. Поместил Header в сторибораде, потом добавил имя и изображение отобразилось. Создал класс и указал UITableViewHeaderFooterView, но выкидывает. Пишет, что для изображения отсутсвует класс. Я указывал, но в итоге автоматом выкидывает. Решил пойти другим методом создал TableViewCell xib. Указал там наследие от UITableViewHeaderFooterView. Добавил все как положено. Сделал функцию указал хедеру ширину. И в функции выдает ошибку выкидывает. Подскажите как правильно сделать HeaderView xib. Уже все уроки пересмотрел и перепробовал. У меня это детальная сцена, и HeaderView типа заголовок, будет содержать изображение и два текста. Будет меняться.Очень буду благодарен за помощь. Вот мой код.

```
import UIKit
import Parse

class DetailSoccerTableViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource,UIScrollViewDelegate  {


    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!



    var detailSoccer: Soccer!

    var selectedSoccer = [Soccer]()


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        self.navigationController!.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: UIBarMetrics.default)
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = true
        self.navigationController!.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear

        title = detailSoccer.detailTitleS

        let nib: UINib = UINib(nibName: "CustomSoccerHeaderView", bundle: nil)
        tableView.register(nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "CustomSoccerHeaderView")
        tableView.tableFooterView = UIView(frame: .zero)
        tableView.sectionHeaderHeight = 350
        tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 288
        tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
        tableView.separatorStyle = .none
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.register(UINib(nibName:"SoccerTableViewCell",bundle:nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "soccerCell")

        tableView.reloadData()
        loadMatchSoccer()
           //Headerc

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)



    }



    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 300
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        let header: CustomSoccerHeaderView = tableView.dequeueReusableHeaderFooterView(withIdentifier: "CustomSoccerHeaderView") as! CustomSoccerHeaderView
        header.nameHeader.text = detailSoccer.detailTitleS
        return header
    }



    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return 2
    }




    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let soccerCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "soccerCell") as! SoccerTableViewCell

        switch indexPath.row {
        case 0:
            soccerCell.titlePrognoz.text = "Аналитика и обзор матча:"
            soccerCell.textSoccer.text = detailSoccer.textSoccer
        case 1:
            soccerCell.titlePrognoz.text = "Прогноз на матч:"
            soccerCell.textSoccer.text = detailSoccer.detailPrognozS
        default:
            break
        }



     return soccerCell


    }






    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    }






func loadMatchSoccer() {

    let query = Soccer.query() as! PFQuery<Soccer>
    query.whereKey("detailTitleS", equalTo: detailSoccer.detailTitleS)
    query.findObjectsInBackground  { (objects, error) in
        if error == nil {

            self.selectedSoccer = objects!

            DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            })

        } else {
            print(error!)
        }
    }
}
}
```

Я понял что надо ее сделать секцией, но как?Пытался повторить как в уроках многих, выдает ошибку.

```
import UIKit

class CustomSoccerHeaderView: UITableViewHeaderFooterView {
    @IBOutlet weak var headerView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var nameHeader: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var imageHeader: UIImageView!
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }


}
```

Comment: [Здесь](https://github.com/SwiftArchitect/SO-31693901) есть пример создания `UITableViewHeaderFooterView` из `xib`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно понял вопрос, то надо создать xib файл `UITableViewHeader` - это наследник `UIView` и его надо создавать как `UIView`.

Описание создания можно посмотреть здесь  [создание UIView xib](https://medium.com/@brianclouser/swift-3-creating-a-custom-view-from-a-xib-ecdfe5b3a960)

Только наследником своего класса укажи `UITableViewHeaderFooterView`

Для создания Footer или Header необходимо реализовать 2 класса в `UITableViewDelegate`

этот `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView?`

Тут создаешь свое кастомное View

и этот `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat`

Тут указываешь высоту своего хедера.

---

Кастомный класс

```
class CastomFooterView: UITableViewHeaderFooterView {


@IBOutlet private var mainView: UIView!
@IBOutlet private weak var dateLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet private weak var backroundView: UIView!

var stringDate: String {
    set {
        dateLabel.text = newValue
    }
    get {
        return dateLabel.text!
    }
}

func cornerFooter() {
    backroundView.layer.cornerRadius = 10
    backroundView.layer.masksToBounds = true
}

override init(reuseIdentifier: String?) {
    super.init(reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    commonInit()
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    commonInit()
}


private func commonInit() {
    Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("CastomFooterView", owner: self, options: nil)
    addSubview(mainView)
    mainView.frame = self.bounds
    mainView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleHeight, .flexibleWidth]
}

}
```

//реализация в таблице (я использую футер, вам же нужен хедер)

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let headerView = CastomFooterView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: 44))
    headerView.stringDate = collectionMesseges[section].header
    headerView.cornerFooter()
    headerView.backgroundView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: ""))
    return headerView
   }


  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 44  // or whatever
  }
```

Comment: Я указал.Щас вот добавлю код.У меня грузиться, но внизу почему то и закреплен.А текст ячейки двигаются.Я же хочу его в верху поставить.

Comment: В стиле таблицы Plain все Headers и Footers имеют анимацию. Если она вам не нужна используйте стиль Grouped, так же он находится внизу потому что используете метод делегата footer, если хотите что-бы заголовок был сверху, используйте header, как я указал выше в примере.

Comment: Так я все сделал, у меня по любому почему то header появляется внизу как футер...можете пару примеров скинуть ? я не могу задать его секцией.Я смотрел в многих уроках, там так показано.

Comment: Замени viewForFooterInSection на viewForHeaderInSection, и heightForFooterInSection на heightForHeaderInSection.

Comment: Да, точно это я не внимателен.Спасибо.